# Getting Errno 9: Bad file descriptor in python socket

Tags: python, sockets

My code is this:

```
while 1:
    # Determine whether the server is up or down
    try:
        s.connect((mcip, port))
        s.send(magic)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
        print data
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    sleep(60)
```

It works fine on the first run, but gives me Errno 9 every time after. What am I doing wrong?

BTW,

```
mcip = "mau5ville.com"
port = 25565
magic = "\xFE"
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You're calling `connect` on the same socket you closed. You can't do that.

As for [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) for `close` say:

> All future operations on the socket object will fail.

Just move the `s = socket.socket()` (or whatever you have) into the loop. (Or, if you prefer, use [`create_connection`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) instead of doing it in two steps, which makes this harder to get wrong, as well as meaning you don't have to guess at IPv4 vs. IPv6, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem in the past,

you have to create the socket before `connect()`:

```
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

then continue with:

```
    s.connect((mcip, port))
    s.send(magic)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print dat
```