# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor in python 3

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I'm a beginning/intermediate level programmer currently trying to write a simple web server in Python 3. However, whenever I run the module I get OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor. I've scoured the internet looking for answers, but I can't seem to figure this one out on my own. Here is the code and traceback:

```
#import socket module

from socket import *

serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

#Prepare a server socket

serverSocket.bind(('IP address', 8000))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
#Establish the connection

 print('Ready to serve...')

 (connectionSocket, addr) = serverSocket.accept()

 print ('connected from',addr)

 try:


      message=connectionSocket.recv(1024)
      filename=message.split()[1]
      print (filename)

      filename=message.split()[1]

      f=open(filename[1:])

      outputdata=f.read()

 #Send one HTTP header line into socket

      connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')

 #Send the content of the requested file to the client

      for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
           connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
           connectionSocket.close()
 except IOError as err:
      print ('IO error')


           #Send response message for file not found

      connectionSocket.send(b'file not found')

                #Close client socket
      connectionSocket.close()
      serverSocket.close()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BigRed/Desktop/SOS/webServer.py", line 17, in <module>
    (connectionSocket, addr) = serverSocket.accept()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line       184, in accept
fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: did you have any IOError error?

Comment: yeah probably didn't need a django tag, it was recommended for whatever reason. Figured maybe a django user might know. Anyways, there WAS an IO error when the code was executed:                        Ready to serve...
connected from ('10.0.0.6', 50077)
b'/helloworld.html'
IO error
Ready to serve...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sockets. OSError: \[Errno 9\] Bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506392/python-sockets-oserror-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor)

Comment: I got this error in Django project test code, where I wasn't mocking a new API call - mocking it solved this for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When there is a OIError, you're calling `serverSocket.close()`. But when you re-enter in the while loop, you call `serverSocket.accept()` without call `serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)`, and this fails, because you've called the `close()`

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958099/2108339)

Hope help

**PD:** django developers don't use socket regularly. =)